# How do I validates input while using Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ransack

I created a search form with multiple search bars by using Ransack, and realized I'd still get search results leaving some input bars blank, even with `validates` codes in the model.

**ticket.rb**

```rb
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  validates :departure, presence: true
  validates :arrival, presence: true 
  validates :departure_date, presence: true
  
end
```

Does anyone know how to validate the right way while using Ransack?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Ransack is a tool to search (read) for existing records, but validations are used to validate records on create or update. I do not understand how you are trying to validate search queries?

Comment: You would need to setup some kind of Service Object to handle this process whereby you can validate the search criteria and then if valid execute the search. Unfortunately as it stands the question is a bit too vague for me to offer any assistance beyond this basic direction.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the reply. As Ransack allows you to leave parts of search input empty, and still shows you search result, I want to make sure all fields are filled, if not there'd be an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You would understand validation flow in complex. Your model received errors after validation, your controller fallback on post action to render edit form and form fields show errors. Short example:

#### app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:

```rb
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = CompanySearchForm.new(name: company_search_params[:name])
    @search.validate
    @companies = Company.ransack(name_eq: company_search_params[:name]).result
  end

  ...
  private

  def company_search_params
    params.require(:company_search_form).permit(:name)
  end

  def search_form
    form = ::CompanySearchForm.new(name: company_search_params[:name])
    form.validate
    form
  end
end
```

#### app/forms/copmany_search_form.rb

```rb
class CompanySearchForm
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  extend ActiveModel::Translation
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
  include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name:)
    @name = name
  end

  def validate
    errors.add(:name, 'search string is too long.') if name.size > 5
  end
end
```

#### app/views/companies/index.html.haml

```rb
= simple_form_for(@search, url: companies_path, method: :get) do |f|
  = f.input :name

  = submit_tag('Search', class: 'btn')

%table
  = @companies.each do |company|
    %tr
      %td= company.id
      %td= company.name
```

For working example go [here](https://github.com/r72cccp/ransack-errors-example), please

Comment: The OP appears to be referring to an unpersisted search object not an ActiveRecord object, so I am not certain that this answers the question in this case. As an aside `create` will fail because `@company` is `nil`

Comment: edited. Thank you!

Comment: @SergioBelevskij Thanks Sergio. Tried custom error message as above, but the errors method is not supported. `NoMethodError (undefined method `errors' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007f8ccf25ba08>):`

Comment: @DerekYi, i'm update example code and add the working example on github.

Comment: Additional comment: right now `valid?` returns `true` if the object is invalid because it returns false if there are no errors (`errors.blank?`). Either change `if` to `unless` or change `blank?` to `any?`

Comment: @SergioBelevskij thanks so much for the edit! I'll try this out!

Comment: Yes. I'm respect too.